# open() python second argument for almost all uses

Tags: python, file, arguments

I'm new in Python and I'm creating a bot for a service called Discord, which maybe you know about.

I'd like to store configurations for users who use the bot in files and I'm quite not understanding how does the second argument of the read() function work.

I've read that depending on the letter you write, you will write the file, read it, etc.

The thing is that I'm quite not understanding how does this work.
If I have read properly, I think it is that mixing letters allows doing different actions.
Can anybody help me out? What string should I need or should I make more than one .read() for that?
I'd like to:

- If the file doesn't exist, create it
- Ability to read the file
- Ability to overwrite the file, setting the entire file to what I insert, not 
  appending it.

If someone could help me out, I'd really like it! Thanks!

Comment: The docs explain what the `mode` argument values mean: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, I just read that before I write the post but didn't get how to "mix" those letters

Comment: What's the *specific problem* you've had trying to implement code using `open`? [Edit] to give a [mcve].

Comment: @Aimarekin what don't you get from it?

Comment: I can't understand how to use the second argument to have the ability to read/write files. Do I need to use open() several times or use a specific second argument?

Comment: To help your basic research: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: As the docs explain, there are many modes. You don't get to mix them, but some modes let you do more than one thing.

Comment: @zvone So I need to use more than one open() to do different functions such as read() and so on?

Comment: If so that was the answer I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def trace_write(file, text_to_trace):
    write_trace = []
    if type(text_to_trace) ==  str:
        with open(file, 'wt+') as w:
            write_trace.append(text_to_trace)
            w.write(text_to_trace+'\n')
    if type(text_to_trace) == list or type(text_to_trace) == tuple:
        with open(file, 'wt+') as w:
            for line in text_to_trace:
                write_trace=text_to_trace
                w.write(line+'\n')
    return write_trace if write_trace != [] else 'Nothing to trace'
```

AFAIK there is no way to do this without opening the file in write mode, then closing the file after the writes are complete, then re-opening in read mode.

In response to the section about opening in a specific mode where it overwrites the file, not append, but also creates the file if it doesn't exist, you're looking to open in `wt+`.

I would expect that if you wanted to "trace" what was written previously, for logging lets says, we could create a new function as written above which handles the writing for us.

Please let me know if there is anything unanswered and I will do my best to amend this for you.

Expected output is below:

[image: expected output:]

I really disagree with storing the information in a text file, purely for overhead's sake. I believe it would be far more suitable to use a pre-existing storage system that is tried and tested. Like, MongoDB or go the whole-hog and set up a database in SQL and the relevant functions you need to store and write to it.

Comment: Thank you! What I was searching for was that"there is no way to do this without opening the file in write mode, then closing the file after the writes are complete, then re-opening in read mode", the other rest of the answer did help too!